# why is my cookie popup button not working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i made a cookie popup for my index page, but and the html and js seems right and should be working but somehow only the orange button works for accepting the cookies, when i click button "Noraidīt" it must disappear but it doesnt do anything, doesnt even console log the message. Can somebody help? Below i provide you with code.

```js
if ( $('.cookie-wrapper').length > 0 ) {


const cookieBox = document.querySelector(".cookie-wrapper"),
acceptBtn = cookieBox.querySelector("button"),
declineBtn = document.querySelector(".decline");

declineBtn.onclick = ()=>{
  console.log("declinebtn");
  document.cookie = "CookieBy=SparkleHeart; max-age="+60*60*24*30;
  if(document.cookie){ //if cookie is set
  
  }else{ //if cookie not set then alert an error
    cookieBox.classList.add("hide"); //hide cookie box
  }
}



acceptBtn.onclick = ()=>{
  //setting cookie for 1 month, after one month it'll be expired automatically
  document.cookie = "CookieBy=SparkleHeart; max-age="+60*60*24*30;
  if(document.cookie){ //if cookie is set
    cookieBox.classList.add("hide"); //hide cookie box
  }else{ //if cookie not set then alert an error
    alert("Cookie can't be set! Please unblock this site from the cookie setting of your browser.");
  }
}
let checkCookie = document.cookie.indexOf("CookieBy=SparkleHeart"); //checking our cookie
//if cookie is set then hide the cookie box else show it
checkCookie != -1 ? cookieBox.classList.add("hide") : cookieBox.classList.remove("hide");

}
```

```css
.cookie-wrapper{
  position: fixed;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  max-width: 818px;
  background: #2F4858;
  border-radius: 8px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.cookie-wrapper.hide{
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
::selection{
  color: #fff;
  background: #FCBA7F;
}


.cookie-content{
  display: flex;
  padding: 32px 46px 28px 32px;
  font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: montserrat-regular;
    line-height: 17px;
}
.cookie-content p{
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 17px;
text-align: left;
margin-right: 56px;
align-self: center;
}

.cookie-content p a{
font-weight: 700;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}
.cookie-content .buttons{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.buttons button{
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 34px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #ffa800;
  border-radius: 50.33px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: montserrat-regular;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 34px;
  width: 131px;
}

.buttons .item:last-child {
  background: #fff;
  color: #2F4858;
  margin-left: 32px;
}

.buttons button:hover{
  transform: scale(0.97);
}

.buttons a{
  color: #FCBA7F;
}


@media (max-width: 680px) {
  .cookie-content .buttons {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .buttons .item:last-child {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .cookie-content {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 12px;
  }

  .cookie-content p {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  
 
  .buttons button {
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100px;

  }

}
```

```html
  <div class="cookie-wrapper">
                <div class="cookie-content">
                  <p>Mēs apkopojam un apstradājām Jūsu personisko informāciju šādiem mērķiem: Analīze.<a href="https://automattic.com/cookies/"> Uzzināt vairāk</a></p>
                  <div class="buttons">
                    <button class="item">Apstriprināt</button>
                    <button class="item decline">Noraidīt</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: Try to avoid mixing jQuery and Vanilla JavaScript. Currently your example isn't running because it's missing a jQuery dependency. You could either include jQuery or remove the single line and replace it with a Vanilla JavaScript version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@blqk, I have tried your code on the Codepen.io, but it works well, even the console log the message "declinebtn". Check this url. "https://codepen.io/devbluesky111/pen/NWpqjzV?editors=1111"
But when I execute your code, I have just added the jQuery CDN. i.e. "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"

Comment: Hello, @blqk, did you check?